# Simple HTML page not served by Tomcat (HTTP 404)

Tags: java, tomcat, config

I am still running into some issues that already have been discussed here, however I still do not know what I am doing wrong.

My application structure is:

```
/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/greeting
        --index.html
        --src
        --META-INF
        --WEB-INF
             --web.xml
             --classes
                   --sk
                      --simo
                          --Greeting.class
```

When requesting `http://localhost:8080/greeting/` I receive an `HTTP 404` response.

When requesting `http://localhost:8080/greeting/hi`, I receive an `HTTP 405` response. This is not an issue, as the `Servlet` only processes `POST` requests.

My question is: How can I make the Tomcat server provide the `index.html` file.

This is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">

        <display-name>Hello, World Application</display-name>
        <description>
            This is a simple web application with a source code organization
           based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
        </description>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/greeting/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Some information on the server:

```
[miso@edubox conf]$ /sbin/tomcat version
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
Server built:   Mar 12 2019 10:11:36 UTC
Server number:  7.0.76.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_212-b04
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Definition of each servlet consists of two parts: 1) Binding  of servlet class to a logical name and 2) Mapping this logical name to URLs.
 In your web.xml you have defined only the 2nd part. Now you should add there also the servlet class name. If you keep your logical name "default", then add following code:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>sk.simo.Greeting</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

2) Alternatively, use `@WebServlet(value="/greeting")`. But then remove your servlet mapping from web.xml.

3) Independent on the answers above, the mapping of folders to context root is important. If you have not change it (I suppose you have not, this is good), then path "/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/greeting" means, that **everything** in your application is available via URLs that have context root "/greeting". It means, if you want to call a servlet via "/greeting/hi", servlet should be mapped to "/hi", not to "/greeting" and not to "/greeting/hi". So use following in your servlet: `@WebServlet(value="/hi")`. This you can call it via ".../greeting/hi".

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by addressing the URL. To make it simple: if your have 10 servlets, how will the server know that "default" means servlet A and not servlet B? To make this clear, the servlet specification *requires* that you specify binding of servlet class name to a logical name. That's why you *should* add the snippet that I provided. Otherwise the application server just *does not know* that there is such a servlet. An alternative is to user @WebServlet. But then remove the logical name from web.xml.

Comment: Yes, I have used @WebServlet. I only attempted to define a mapping so that index.html is served. However, it's not even if i delete all from the web.xml. Most recently I deleted all <servlet*> definitions but URL http://localhost:8080/greeting/ still returns 404.

Comment: hi, speaking about your point 3: this is something i understand and the "app" really does what it should when URL ../greeting/hi is accessed. the issue is it never shows the index.html file, although as i understand it should when localhost:8080/greeting is accessed. do you have any ideas?

Comment: By `<url-pattern>/greeting/*</url-pattern>` you forward all requests to non-existing servlet. Remove this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was an errorneous redeployment. As soon as I deleted the app's top level directory "greeting" and restored its contents, the `index.html` finally has shown up.

The servlet mapping now follows the example of the Tomcat 7 "sample" app:

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Greeting</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sk.simo.Greeting</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Greeting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hi</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I reference it via:

```
<form action="hi" method="POST">
```

This works fine.